# How spark2.0 to connect to hive-jdbc-1.1.0

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, hive

I have a question.When i run my spark task , with hive-jdbc in local ,i can connect the hive .But when i run it in cluster with spark-submit,it failed .

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://172.16.28.99:10000/vdm_da_dev.db: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=vdm_da_dev.db})"

The client is `hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0`,and the server is `hive-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.`
But the spark is `spark-2.0.0`,the hive-jdbc in `/opt/spark/jars` is `hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar`.

I replace it with `hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar` of all nodes,but still the wrong .

I package the project with dependencies,but in the spark-submit,it did not use them.
How can i do it?

Please,anyone can help me . Thanks very much.

Comment: What is the version your hive client and version of hive server?

Comment: hive client version:hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0;
hive server version:hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0
the same! when put a jar whitout spark task ,just connect to hive and create a table in the server ,it success.
But when i connect to hive in the spark task ,also with hive-jdbc,it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks FaigB very much!

I did as @FaigB told,but i found there were no the dependence jars in dependency classpath.

Then i removed all the hive dependence jars in /opt/spark/jars/,and copy them from /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/jars/.Then i solved the mistake of mismatched version.

Just like:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark   138464 8月  19 13:55 hive-beeline-1.2.1.spark2.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark    37995 11月 15 01:00 hive-cli-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark    40817 8月  19 13:55 hive-cli-1.2.1.spark2.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark 11498852 8月  19 13:55 hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark    95006 11月  9 14:59 hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark   100680 8月  19 13:55 hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark  5505200 8月  19 13:55 hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark  1874242 11月 15 01:00 hive-service-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark  1033763 8月  19 13:55 spark-hive_2.11-2.0.0.jar_bk
-rw-r--r--. 1 spark spark  1813851 8月  19 13:55 spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.0.jar_bk

[spark@d2 jars]$ cp  hive-service-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
[spark@d2 jars]$ cp hive-cli-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
[spark@d2 jars]$ cp spark-hive_2.10-1.5.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
[spark@d2 jars]$ cp hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
[spark@d2 jars]$ cp hive-metastore-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
[spark@d2 jars]$ cp hive-beeline-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar /opt/spark/jars/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use guide from cloudera for additional parameters:
[running spark apps on cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_apps.html#concept_rt4_f4m_zs)

In general spark-submit should look like:

```
spark-submit --class *class_main* \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf "key=value" \
--files path_to_spark_conf/hive-site.xml \
--jars full_path/addiational_dependecy_jars \
app_package.jar
```

In `--jars` possibly you should provide `datanucleus-core, datanucleus-rdbms, datanucleus-api-jdo` in order to work with hive and hive metastore.

Comment: Thanks very much.
 I did it like :
  `/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit  
--class  com.BinlogCombinerZK \ 
--master yarn  \ 
--files /opt/spark/conf/hive-site.xml \
--executor-memory 8G  --executor-cores 4  \ 
--jars /jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar,/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar \ /home/datadev_nbdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar       60 > spark.log`
There was still the wrong.
`Caused by:TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=vdm_da_dev.db})`